# Empty migration fille in Entity Framework Core - there are only two empty methods Up() and Down()

Tags: database, entity-framework

I am creating a simple database using Entity Framework Core (EF Core 7) and I encountered a strange problem.

When I am trying to update my database and create migration using

```
dotnet ef migrations add ExampleMigration
```

the migration file remains with only two methods with no body at all.

[The thing is everything is building and compiling as you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hKYW.png)

And after the process finish migration file looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace bazy_lab_entity.Migrations
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class NotNullProductsList : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The context file:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;

namespace bazy_lab_entity
{
    public class ProductContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Datasource=ProductsDatabase");
        }
    }
}
```

My tables look like this:

```
namespace bazy_lab_entity
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public int UnitsOnStock { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace bazy_lab_entity
{
    public class Supplier
    {
        public int SupplierId { get; set; }
        public string? CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string? Street { get; set; }
        public string? City { get; set; }
        public List<Product> ProductsList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here are project settings:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.4">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="7.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="ProdcutDatabase">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="ProductsDatabase">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Migrations\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Here are the things I have already tried:

1. Adding virtual to context file

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;

namespace bazy_lab_entity
{
    public class ProductContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Datasource=ProductsDatabase");
        }
    }
}
```

2. Deleting the context snapshot model.
3. Deleting whole database and recreating it again.

I tried every method multiple times.

I don't really now how to fix it. I feel hopeless at that point.

I will be so glad and thankful if someone would help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding relationship configurations will fix it.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Supplier>()
        .HasMany(s => s.ProductsList)
        .WithOne(p => p.Supplier)
        .IsRequired();

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```